# Remove backslash from JSON string and print value of a key

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I am trying to print values corresponding to keys of JSON Key value pairs.

This JSON output is retrieved using event_response and it is shown below.
I want to print values of Effect and Action so as to match it with a regular expression and take action. I want to get values without backslash so as to match with the regular expression.
I tried replace but it didn't worked

```
    if "responseElements" in event['detail'].keys():
        event_response = \
            event["detail"]["responseElements"]["policy"]
        print(event_response) 
        policy_details = json.loads("event_response")
        print(policy_details)
```

```
{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"apigateway.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":[\"logs:CreateLogGroup\",\"logs:CreateLogStream\",\"logs:DescribeLogGroups\",\"logs:DescribeLogStreams\",\"logs:PutLogEvents\",\"logs:GetLogEvents\"],\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}
```

Comment: What value do you get when you print `event_response` ?

Comment: event_response gives the output mentioned in the question comprising of Version, Statement etc.

Comment: Oh ok, just double checking as you had two prints on your code snippet.

Comment: `json.loads("event_response")` cannot possibly work. Do you mean `json.loads(event_response)` without quotes? It looks like that value isn't proper JSON either -- probably use an interface which produces JSON instead, or figure out which format you should use to decode this.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, then beautiful design without backslash is required. You can use the `pprint` module:

```py
import pprint
pprint.pprint(json.loads(event_response ))
```

result:

```
{'Statement': [{'Action': ['logs:CreateLogGroup',
                           'logs:CreateLogStream',
                           'logs:DescribeLogGroups',
                           'logs:DescribeLogStreams',
                           'logs:PutLogEvents',
                           'logs:GetLogEvents'],
                'Effect': 'Allow',
                'Principal': {'Service': 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'},
                'Resource': '*'}],
 'Version': '2012-10-17'}
```

Comment: How to retrieve the keys "Effect" and "Resource" from the above JSON content. Kindly help.

Comment: For example above:
`effect = json.loads(event_response)['Statement'][0]['Effect']` `resource = json.loads(event_response)['Statement'][0]['Resource']`

Comment: I executed and added only effect statement but getting following errors :- Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1): JSONDecodeError

Comment: try change quotes to double quotes: effect = json.loads(event_response)["Statement"][0]["Effect"]. Try to execute step by step `effect = json.loads(event_response)` - No error? `effect = json.loads(event_response)["Statement"]` and further

Comment: if your json is not in `event_response`, but in `policy_details` then change code to `effect = json.loads(policy_details)`

Comment: if your json (event_response or policy_details) contains single quotes then try to replace them: `effect = json.loads(event_response.replace("\'", "\""))["Statement"][0]["Effect"]`

Comment: I executed this :-             event_response = \
                event["detail"]["responseElements"]["policy"]  
            print(event_response)
            effect = json.loads(event_response)

Comment: {\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"apigateway.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":[\"logs:CreateLogGroup\",\"logs:CreateLogStream\",\"logs:DescribeLogGroups\",\"logs:DescribeLogStreams\",\"logs:PutLogEvents\",\"logs:GetLogEvents\"],\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}

Comment: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1): JSONDecodeError

Comment: Latest two comments above have the output. please help.

Comment: I can not understand the problem. I write your json string `test = json.loads('{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\", ....    ....\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}')` to python shell. And then print(test) execute without problem

Comment: I did some debugging of the issue. I executed the below code :-

Comment: event_response = \
                event["detail"]["responseElements"]["policy"]
            test = json.loads('{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"apigateway.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":[\"logs:CreateLogGroup\",\"logs:CreateLogStream\",\"logs:DescribeLogGroups\",\"logs:DescribeLogStreams\",\"logs:PutLogEvents\",\"logs:GetLogEvents\"],\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}')
 print(test)
test1 = test["Statement"][0]["Effect"]
print(test1)
test2 = json.loads('event_response')
print(test2)

Comment: Output is as follows :-

Comment: {'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Effect': 'Allow', 'Principal': {'Service': 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'}, 'Action': ['logs:CreateLogGroup', 'logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:DescribeLogGroups', 'logs:DescribeLogStreams', 'logs:PutLogEvents', 'logs:GetLogEvents'], 'Resource': '*'}]}